# internal_error.html with rails 3 app on DreamHost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dreamhost

I have a rails 3 app on DreamHost. Randomly I get an error like the following.

```
Started GET "/internal_error.html" for ...

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/internal_error.html"):
```

I created a sample page.
It just posts data and the controller just redirects it without processing the data.
The error happens while redirecting.(randomly 1 out of 10 times)

I contacted DreamHost support and they said that it's not triggered by the server but the application.
I think the application is too simple to cause errors.
I suspect it's the passenger that causes the error.

Does anybody have any idea about this error?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: as a side note, you should be using heroku, not dreamhost.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this issue. It is happening to me too.

Comment: Any luck with this issue? I'm having it too but the below didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does seem to be a problem with dreamhost specifically.  I get the error when calling redirect_to in an update action, just like the poster in this thread on the dreamhost forums:

http://discussion.dreamhost.com/archive/index.php/thread-130022.html

In my case, however, the data *is* being updated before the internal error.  So the recommendation of adding `sleep 0.5` before the redirection fixed the problem for me.  Not sure if it will work in your case, though, since I have no idea what is causing the problem in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround.

I created a controller and an action.
/internal_error/index

```
def index
  render :layout => false
end

[index.html.erb]
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0">
</head>
<html>
<title>Redirect</title>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

It works for me.